# How to show post edit page for user who is author?

Tags: php, laravel

I want to give access to the edit page only to the authors of the posts.

`PostController`:

```
public function edit(Vocabulary $vocabulary)
{
    if ($vocabulary->user_id != Auth::id()) {
        return redirect()
            ->route('home')
            ->with('danger', 'You cannot edit another user's vocabulary.');
    }

    // return view...
}
```

---

So, my question is **how to compact this part of the code**. Can I use fewer code lines for this *(because I must write such blocks in lots of methods)*?

```
// I'm checking current User's id and author's id in the post..
if ($vocabulary->user_id != Auth::id()) { 
    return redirect()
        ->route('home')
        ->with('danger', "You cannot edit another user's vocabulary.");
}
```

Comment: Check out Policies https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/authorization

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I highly recommend to use Laravel **Policy** classes to handle it. Simply you just have to make a Policy class for each model you want to give access to. So in policy class you can implement different algorithms for each action such as **update**, **delete** etc. 
You can find more information in the link below:

[Writing Policies](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/authorization#creating-policies)

Comment: Yes, i tried everything, but got an error `This action is unauthorized.`.. So, i dont now how to make this correctly..

Comment: Ok so it throws 403 exception

Comment: You can make a view blade file in your views/errors directory named 403.blade.php

Comment: In that view file you can show appropriate message for all unauthorized actions

Answer (score 0):

Using Middleware in the edit page and add it to its route and if the auth user is author then pass it else show the error

```
public function checkAuthor($Request , closure $next)
{
  If( CONDITION FOR CHECKING AUTHOR) {
        return response(error message)
    }
    return $next($Request)
}
```

I guess it will help

Comment: You "guess" it will help?